# How to Change link (nameOfController?a=1&b=5&c=20&d=30) in Custom PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm trying to retrieve some data from database with the help of the values in the link uisng the GET method... and working with Custom php MVC..

since im still a beginner, I don't know to access data send from a form in page 1 to another form in page 2..

This is the regular way.

Example

**page1.php**

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo URL"./page2.".php ;?> ">
    <select name="a">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="b">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="c">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   </select>
    <input type="submit" value="continue">
</form>
```

when submitting the form the page 2 will be like this

**page2.php?a=1&b=5&c=20&d=30**

```
    <select name="a">
        <option value="1" <?php echo($_GET['a']=='1')? 'selected': '';?>>Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php echo($_GET['a']=='2')? 'selected': '';?>>Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="b">
        <option value="1" <?php echo($_GET['b']=='1')? 'selected': '';?>>Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php echo($_GET['b']=='2')? 'selected': '';?>>Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="c">
        <option value="1" <?php echo($_GET['c']=='1')? 'selected': '';?>>Option 1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php echo($_GET['a']=='2')? 'selected': '';?>>Option 2</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

How to change this method to an MVC method like : ..../nameOfController/.......

> **NB: I know the basis of MVC.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in a native way but you can accomplish such things thanks to a couple of works :

Since the file "nameOfController" does not necessarily exist in your application, you'll need to trick a bit and i'll try to describe as clearly as possible how most of MVC frameworks handle such request :

- There is a "main" file which will catch every single request and allow the framework to interprete it. For example, it's called "index.php" in Zend Framework or "app.php" in Symfony.
- An ".htaccess" file with some rules will redirect every single request you want to your main file so your main file will be able to analyze them. You can specify in those rules that you don't want Apache to redirect requests leading to real resources on your server (images, css files, etc.)
- Then, there is something that looks like a "router"/"dispatcher" module which will call the specific controller and the specific method according to the shape of the request and of rules you've decided.

It's up to you then to declare your own rules and what you want your app to do (folders containing controllers, the name of traditional methods of controllers, etc.)

I hope this will help you, sorry for my bad english

---

Edit : here is an example :

Let's imagine we have an .htaccess file. I'll take Symfony example on purpose :

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Globally, this script does redirect every request (except pointing on physicaly existing resources) on a file named "app.php". This file "app.php" is designed to be the starter of your application and contains the code below :

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
// Enable APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// You should change the ApcClassLoader first argument to a unique prefix
// in order to prevent cache key conflicts with other applications
// also using APC.
/*
$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);
$loader->unregister();
$apcLoader->register(true);
*/
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

This one loads the kernel (which is the code of the Symfony framework) and tries to recompose the requests thanks to PHP global variables :

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

Then, the kernel handles our request :

```
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

which results in a response.

We can imagine that the handle method "analyses" the request method (which corresponds to your HTTP request) and will try to deduct the controller it has to reach and which method it should call.

Globally, a SF app and its modules (which can define different parts of a website for example) is designed this way : there is a "src" folder which contains "bundles" (modules) and thoses bundles belong to their own namespace, e.g Com\MyAppBundle\, Com\BlogBundle\, Com\AdminBundle\, etc.

Each bundle can contain controllers (resulting namespace : Com\MyAppBundle\Controller), forms (Com\MyAppBundle\Form) and so on, and the kernel will try to find the correct resource to reach. It usually follow the PSR-4 and PSR-0 namespace format.

To know which controller can be reached for a specific kind of URL, Symfony allows you to define "routes" which associate a URL pattern with specific rules.

Example of route coming right from Symfony (.yml file) :

```
bloc_article_show:
    pattern:  /blog/article/{id}/
    defaults: { _controller: "ComMyAppBundle:Blog:show" }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
```

This rule, named "bloc_article_show" is a custom rule which says that for an URL which match the following pattern /blog/article/{id}/ (e.g /blog/article/9/), then the kernel should dispatch the request to the controller named BlogController which belongs to the Com\MyAppBundle\ namespace. Once this controller is reached, the method "show" is called with $id as a parameter. We also specify that the "id" parameter must be a digit [0-9]+

**WARNING : /bloc/article/ IS NOT an existing directory/folder ;)**

This is a straight example coming from Symfony but most of the existing framework do something pretty similar :) Then it's up to you to define the way your MVC application will catch requests and dispatch them.

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: @SpyDer I've added an example to the original post, tell me if you find it useful :)